# jasmine test override service method

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I'm testing a component which uses an authService and there is a method inside that calls another service and returns an observable boolean value. I'm trying to override the method and simply return true when it's called.

I have tried the below, but the actual method is being called.

```
it('should', () => {
  authService.method = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(true)
  fixture.detectChanges()
  component.onSubmit();
  expect(component.errorMessage).toEqual('error');
})
```

Comment: where are you passing the mocked auth service, is it dependency injected ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
it('should set errorMessage', () => {
  spyOn(authService, 'method').and.returnValue(of(true));
  component.onSubmit();
  expect(component.errorMessage).toEqual('error');
});
```